# How to get other BSM measurements

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

Currently, the omnetpp.ini file in [this configuration of veremi](https://github.com/VeReMi-dataset/veins/tree/securecomm2018) gets only position and speed of the BSM messages. How can I obtain and add the other values of a BSM message to this as well (acceleration, heading, and yawrate specifically)? And where can I locate the code that gets these values in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

I think the code you are loking for is here: https://github.com/VeReMi-dataset/veins/blob/securecomm2018/src/veins/modules/application/tracingapp/TracingApp.cc

Specifically:

```
const Coord TracingApp::getMyPosition() const {
    return mobility->getPositionAt(simTime());
}

const double TracingApp::getMySpeed() const {
    return mobility->getSpeed();
}
```

It already has an angle function as well.